# Does a child die from malaria every two minutes?

Tags: mortality, children, virus, malaria

> A child dies from malaria every two minutes.

-- *[CNN article on Faso Soap](http://www.cnn.com/2016/05/18/africa/faso-soap-malaria-bukrina-faso/?iid=ob_lockedrail_bottomlist)*

This doesn't sound right to me. I know Africa (the main location of malaria) is a big and populous place, but this seems too much. Is it true that a child dies from malaria every two minutes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [World Health Organization](http://www.who.int/features/factfiles/malaria/malaria_facts/en/index2.html):

> More than two thirds (70%) of all malaria deaths occur in this age group. In 2015, **about 305,000 African children died before their fifth birthdays**.

This data was used by an African organization [africacheck.org](https://africacheck.org/reports/does-an-african-child-die-from-malaria-every-30-seconds/) when trying to estimate the number of malaria deaths in children under 5 in Africa:

[image]

Then, using a middle estimate, they calculated on average how many children die on every minute:

[image]

The African organization was responding to a study from the University of St George's London that concluded that a child dies [every 30 seconds](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2016/01/160112144441.htm):

> One child dies from malaria every 30 seconds in Africa, but a new treatment strategy could help healthcare workers tackle the disease in a simpler way, research has revealed.

The African organization [later said](https://africacheck.org/reports/does-an-african-child-die-from-malaria-every-30-seconds/#sthash.1n66ybr1.dpuf):

> Earlier this year a science news website **claimed that an African child dies of malaria every 30 seconds**. But the latest and best estimate shows that it is just under **every two minutes**.

Comment: It should be noted that, technically statements of the form "*X happens every Y seconds/minutes/hours/etc.*" generally cannot be literally correct, but instead must be assumed to have "*on average*" implicitly appended.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Here's to 'that one guy' who starts counting and at every 15 second interval goes 'dead!'.